# AC signals read by voltmeter and ammeter

Tags: electric-circuits

What will be the reading if we connect an AC voltage and current to a voltmeter and an ammeter, respectively?

I guess it will read the RMS values. Is that right? If yes, why?

Comment: -1 What kind of [voltmeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltmeter) and [ammeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammeter)?

Answer (score 1):

AC voltmeters and ammeters measure the RMS values of voltage and current, *by design*. We design AC meters this way because the RMS value is associated to the power that an AC source delivers to a load.

However, measuring accurately the RMS value is a complex and, possibly, expensive task. Therefore, cheap meters make an approximate measurement through average-responding detectors: this means that for non-sinusoidal signals this kind of meters have significant measurement errors.